# Where did "Find Album Artwork" go?

Tags: itunes, music, apple-music

I just upgraded iTunes to version 12.4.1.6, and now when I right click on a song the option of "Find Album Artwork" is gone.
I use that option when I add new songs that aren't imported with it. (I don't like the "find all" option because it messes up some custom artworks I've added)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It should still be there, just with a slightly different name: **Get Album Artwork**.

[image]